# Django : Template not found/index.html

Tags: python, django

I am running a website using Django. There is no problem in login. When i logged in and click on some dashboard, it is showing "page not found"(404).

Views.py:

```
def index(request):
return(request,'obs_app/index.html')
```

Settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates/index.html')
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        'libraries':  {
            'get_by_index':'obs_app.templatetags.templatefilters',
            'get_by_key':'obs_app.templatetags.templatefilters',
            'get_dict':'obs_app.templatetags.templatefilters',
            'get_items':'obs_app.templatetags.templatefilters',
            'multiple':'obs_app.templatetags.templatefilters',
        },
    },
},
]
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from obs_app import views
urlpatterns = [
url(r'index/',views.index , name = 'index'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
path('dashboard',views.obs_index, name='admin_dash'),
path('halls/active',views.obs_halls_active,name='active-halls'),
path('halls/pending',views.obs_halls_pending,name='pending-halls'),
path('febs/userlist', views.febs_user_list, name='febs-users'),
path('bookings/user', views.bookings_user, name='bookings-users'),
path('bookings/owner', views.bookings_owner, name='bookings-owner'),
path('cancellation/user', views.cancelled_user, name='cancelled-user'),
path('cancellation/owner', views.cancelled_owner, name='cancelled-owner'),
path('terms/obs', views.terms_conditions, name='terms-conditions'),
path('terms/febs', views.terms_febs, name='terms-febs'),
path('terms/febs/events', views.terms_febs_events, name='terms-febs-events'),
```

Error i am getting is :
Page not found (404)
The current path, index.html, didn't match any of these.

Comment: change to `return render(request,'index.html')`

Comment: Your `TEMPLATE_DIR` is expected to be a directory, not a template file.

Comment: The 404 is a separate issue to 'Template Not Found'. The template name and URL are separate in Django. You have `url(r'index/`, ...)`, so you would go to `/index/` in your browser, not `index.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to render template and also fix the indentation

```
def index(request):
   return render(request,'obs_app/index.html')
```

And also here you need to provide directory instead of file

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates/index.html')
```

To:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

---

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [],    # DIRS defines a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files, in search order.
        ...
    },
]
```

You might want to read: [Support for template engines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines)

Related part copied here:

> DIRS defines a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files, in search order.